# Why doesn't my camouflage save between different servers in Battlefield 3?

Tags: pc, battlefield-3

Going from server to server is nice to mix up the game play, but it becomes a major hassle when every time I connect, I have to modify some of my player's settings: mainly, my player's camouflage.  It is a pain to have to do this every time if I do not want to use the default camo - which sticks out like a sore thumb.

Is there any file I can modify or a setting I am missing to keep my player's settings between servers?

Comment: It's weird. Just yesterday I realized it wasn't saving my kits between servers it seemed. (this was on xbox)

Comment: My weapon kits usually save (custom weapon load out) but the kit I want to use per class - usually doesn't either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work inconsistently for many users.

Although undocumented, this is probably a bug.
I would assume that when you make the change it saves it temporarily to your machine and then tries to sync it to the cloud.

If it doesn't sync it to the cloud and the temporary cache expires, it forgets what you did.

That's my best guess. It will probably be fixed in a future patch but since it's probably considered a "minor" issue - it may be a while.

Comment: My assumption was a bug, but can you source this?

Comment: I made a valiant attempt! But alas there does not appear to be any "confirmed" bug. It has been stated on other forums that they have not confirmed it or publicly talked about it and that it does not appear to be receiving attention because it's such a low priority.

Comment: Best I can do...

http://forums.electronicarts.co.uk/battlefield-3/1464556-list-bugs-battlefield-3-a.html

"The game does not save the camouflage we choose. Forcing us to choose again when a new round begins."